# I can't connect to ASDM on my LAN with the enabled inside address shown in CLI

Tags: cisco-asa

newbie here.

Despite the console config here-under, I can't connect to ASA and launch ASDM config from LAN's PC.
The latest JAVA is installed, but I get a "This page can't be displayed" message on Internet explorer v.11, trying to connect with address: https://192.168.1.0

I can connect from outside though.

Here is my console session info:

```
ciscoasa# show run http
http server enable 441
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 inside
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the full configuration. You can obfuscate the public addresses and the passwords, but we really need to see everything else.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Ron, will do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by this line of config :

```
http server enable 441
```

you have enabled the ASDM on the port 441 and to access ASDM from the browser you need to spicify the port when you connect and you need the inside the inside interface IP not the subnet address 192.168.1.0